# Fetch Unique record of one field and also combine with order by another field

Tags: mysql, google-bigquery

I would like to fetch the unique record[studentName] from student collection 
based on joining date

Example: student [TableName]

```
studentName     joiningDate
Rosy             2018-06-25
Meera            2018-07-20                  
Rosy             2018-06-20
```

I have tried this below query but it does not worked.

select distinct(studentName) from student order by joiningDate

I want the result like this,

```
studentName     joiningDate
Rosy             2018-06-25
Meera            2018-07-20
```

Comment: Which joiningDate will you pick in case of duplicates ?

Comment: I want to fetch unique student name based on recent joining date in case if joining date its duplicated.Need to fetch unique student name.

Answer (score 2):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL and works for any number of additional fields in that table w/o changing the query

```
#standardSQL 
SELECT AS VALUE ARRAY_AGG(t ORDER BY joiningDate DESC LIMIT 1)[OFFSET(0)]
FROM `project.dataset.student` t
GROUP BY studentName
```

You can test, play with above using dummy data from your question:

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.student` AS (
  SELECT 'Rosy'studentName, '2018-06-25' joiningDate UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Meera', '2018-07-20' UNION ALL                  
  SELECT 'Rosy', '2018-06-20' 
) 
SELECT AS VALUE ARRAY_AGG(t ORDER BY joiningDate LIMIT 1)[OFFSET(0)]
FROM `project.dataset.student` t
GROUP BY studentName
```

with result

```
Row studentName joiningDate  
1   Rosy        2018-06-25   
2   Meera       2018-07-20
```

Answer (score 0):

Should try `GROUP BY` instead, like this:

```
SELECT studentName, MIN(joiningDate)
FROM student
GROUP BY studentName
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Group By` with [`Max()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_max) aggregation function (to get recent joining date). Try the following query instead:

```
SELECT studentName, 
       MAX(joiningDate) AS joiningDate
FROM student 
GROUP BY studentName
ORDER BY joiningDate ASC
```